# proving the equation has 4 roots using intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus, functions, polynomials, continuity, roots

**how do I prove with intermediate value theorem
that the equation $(x^2/10)-4$=$x/(x^2-4)$ has 4 roots**

```
I tried moving the sides of the equations to make assisted function
f(x)= (x^2/10)-(x/(x^2-4))-4
and assigned value x>2,x>-2,-2<x<2 to find when f(x)>0 and when f(x)<0 
is that a correct way to solve the problem??
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Multiplying both sides by $x^2 - 4$, let $\displaystyle f(x) = \left\{\left[\frac{x^2}{10} - 4\right] \times \left[x^2 - 4\right]\right\} - x,~$ where it is understood that $f(x)$ is undefined at $x = \pm 2.$  Then $f(x) = 0$ is a 4th degree equation that has at most $4$ real roots.  To prove that $f(x),~$ which is a continuous function, except at the points where it is undefined (i.e. $x = \pm 2$), crosses the $x$ axis $4$ times, I advise examining the 1st and 2nd derivatives of $f(x)$.  This will allow you to study the behavior of $f(x)$.  ...see next comment

Comment: Note that if (for example) $2 < a < b$, and $f(a) < 0 < f(b)$, then since $f(x)$ is continuous on the interval $[a,b]$, $f(x)$ must cross the $x$-axis at least once in the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: In response to your latest question, see my previous comments.  My version of $f(x)$ involves *clearing the* *denominator* of $(x^2 - 4)$.  Further, my approach then involves studying the behavior of $f(x)$ by examining its 1st and 2nd derivatives.  Suppose for example that there is some interval $[a,b]$ that does not contain either $x = +2$, or $x = -2$.  Suppose further that $f'(x)$ is always positive in this interval and that $f(a) < 0 < f(b)$.  Then the interval $[a,b]$ will contain **exactly** one real root.  ...see next comment

Comment: Re the $[a,b]$ sample interval in the previous comment, suppose (for example) that $f'(a) > 0$ and that $f''(x) > 0$ throughout the $[a,b]$ interval.  Then, $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing throughout the $[a,b]$ interval and is therefore positive throughout this interval.  This implies that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing throughout this interval.

Comment: Use mathjax. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.